# vertical align does not work in HTML

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I create a table with CSS ,and I want to cell values to be in middle vertical align.I use this CSS code :

```
div.cell
{
   float: right;
   border-left: 1px #293F6F solid;
   border-bottom: 1px #293F6F solid;
   height: 55px;
   width: 27%;
   text-align: center;

   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

and my html code :

```
<div class="cell">XYZ</div>
```

But It does not work.also other vertical-align types such as "text-bottom" and "bottom" and "top" dont work.Regards

Comment: The issue is caused by `float: right;` ... vertical-align only works for inline objects, not floating ones. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/122290/83605

Comment: You may also want to read this: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Protip: Don't float cells. use `display:inline-block` and set `font-size` of parent element to `0` to avoid extra markup. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `float: right;` is important I suggest removing the `height: 55px;` of the div and use `padding-top/bottom` to position the text.